# Does a Text-Adventure game actually need hundreds of different activities?

Tags: java, android

This may be a silly question - It's actually been a month since I've started learning Java so I apologize beforehand.

I have started making an Android game similar to the quite famous Lifeline: text-adventure, where you make your own path after you keep choosing between 2 choices. When you click on one of the choices, then two new ones appear (and above them, the question that the protagonist asks you to keep you going).

So, lets say that every choice is unique: thinking of it as a "family tree" on paper, if we start with a question with 2 choices, then we get to 4 possible ones (for example, Yes leads to YES-NO and No leads to MAYBE-MAYBE NOT), then 8, then with the next choice there are 16 unique ones etc. Eventually, after 10 clicks, in the complete game there would be 1024 different choices.

My question is: do I have to make an activity for each different question giving you 2 choices? Creating 1000+ activities for a text-based game sounds... not fun at all. And also, do I really have to make every single text I write, questions and choices, a string?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my way of describing my problem.

Comment: Instead you could have one activity that changes itself acording to some data.

Comment: This probably belongs in a different Stack Exchange like maybe Game Development but to answer your question no, you don't.  You could have paths link back up to limit activity count, have a single activity with some random stuff that could be inserted, stuff like that.  Plus you don't have to guarantee each activity has two options.  One path could kill off your player in three choices if you wanted.

Comment: To elaborate on what others have said, you can do this with really just one activity, perhaps add different ones if you want a significant layout change at some point in the story. Your activity just manipulates the data and controls how it is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **NO**

---

**How to do it?**

You should plan it out at first.

Putting paths and questions in arrays.

And using the same activity but changing the data written.

I won't give you exact steps but these are hints, you can even make custom classes instead.